# Iterate in RUN command in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, sh, dockerfile

I have a line that looks something like:

```
RUN for i in `x y z`; do echo "$i"; done
```

...with the intention of printing each of the three items

But it raises `/bin/sh: 1: x: not found`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what image are you using to build your container?

Comment: Currently off an `ubuntu` image

Comment: can you build your container without that `RUN` command then do a `docker run -it <whatever you named the container> bash` and then try running the bash command on the terminal given to see if it works? Also do a `which sh`

Comment: `which sh` returns `/bin/sh`. Unfortunately the docker run launches a python process, but I can disentangle that if the `/bin/sh` isn't enough info

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It looks like you're using backticks. What's in backticks gets executed and the text in the backticks gets replaced by what's returned by the results.

<strike>Try using single quotes or double quotes instead of backticks</strike>.

Try getting rid of the backticks like so:

```
RUN for i in x y z; do echo "$i"; done
```

Comment: nice catch! yea, he just needs to do the command with `"1 2 3"` instead of `\`1 2 3\``

Comment: I now get this (with 'each' added to show it's an array):

`Step 5 : RUN for i in 'x y z'; do echo "each $i"; done`
`---> Running in 2c828be77f13`
`each x y z`

What am I doing wrong such that it's not recognizing it's an array?

Comment: So it is iterating over something? What is the exact error you get? Is it that x, y and z are variables and they are being interpreted like plain letters?

Comment: It's not iterating over it - it's treating it as a single item. The expected output would be `each x` `each y` `each z`

Comment: get rid of the quotes and try it.

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest an alternative solution of this.

In stead of having the LOOP inside docker file, can we take a step back ...

Implement the loop inside a independent bash script;

Which means you would have a loop.sh as following:

`#!/bin/bash`

`for i in $(seq 1 5); do echo "$i"; done`

And in your Dockerfile, you will need to do:

```
COPY loop.sh loop.sh
RUN ./loop.sh
```

With the approach aboved it requires one extra step and costs one extra layer.

However, when you are going to do some more complicated stuff, I would recommend to put them all into the script.

All the operations inside the script will only cost one layer.

To me this approach is could be cleaner and more maintainable.

Please also have a read at this one:
https://hackernoon.com/tips-to-reduce-docker-image-sizes-876095da3b34

Comment: Both solutions only create one layer... Whatever command you RUN, loop or not, is transparent to docker and there will always be one layer created.

Comment: And don't forget that you can only do `RUN ./loop.sh` if you remembered to copy it from your host context into the docker image with `COPY loop.sh loop.sh`

Answer (score 10):

For a more maintainable `Dockerfile`, my preference is to use multiple lines with comments in `RUN` instructions especially if chaining multiple operations with `&&`

```
RUN sh -x \
    #
    # execute a for loop
    #
    && for i in x  \
                y  \
                z; \
       do \
              echo "$i"
       done \
    \
    #
    # and tell builder to have a great day
    #
    && echo "Have a great day!"
```

Comment: and if you want to use "BASH" inside the RUN-command (and not just "sh"), write this line one line above the RUN: `SHELL: ["/bin/bash","-c"]`

Answer (score 2):

We can do it like

```
RUN for i in x \y \z; do echo "$i" "hi"; done
```

output of above command will be

---

x hi 
y hi 
z hi

---

Mind spaces while writing - for i in x \y \z; 
example - snippet from git bash 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run Docker container perpetually by writing a simple script

```
docker run -d <container id> \
sh -c "while :; do echo 'just looping here... nothing special'; sleep 1; done"
```